# Find $p$, such that $\frac1{20} = (1 - p)^{19}p$

Tags: analysis, polynomials, roots

I need help to solve for $p$, where $p$ is a probability, i.e. it lies in the interval $[0,1]$.

$$\frac1{20} = (1 - p)^{19}p.$$

How would one solve for $p$?

Thnx

Comment: is this supposed to be a binomial distribution?

Comment: I think I apporached the question wrongly. The question was to find  a surmised/estimated p(probability), from a guy who wins on a spinning wheel after the twentieth try. Find the parametrisised p*.       Now I do know how to find it, and had to use mean something method.

Answer (score 5):

First observe that: $(f(p)=(1-p)^{19}p>0$ iff $p\in(0,1)$, while $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and thus $f$ attains a maximum in $(0,1)$.

Next, let's maximize $f(x)=(1-x)^{19}x$. We have
$$
0=f'(x)=(1-x)^{19}-19(1-x)^{18}x,
$$
which implies that
$$
1-x-19x=0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=\frac{1}{20}.
$$
But
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)=\frac{1}{20}\left(1-\frac{1}{20}\right)^{19}<\frac{1}{20}.
$$
Thus $(1-p)^{19}p<1/20$, for all $p\in\mathbb R$.

**Note.** Our calculations demonstrate that 
$$
\sup_{p\in(0,1)}(1-p)^{n-1}p \approx \frac{1}{n\mathrm{e}},
$$
when $n\gg 1$.

Comment: It is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n\mathrm{e}}$. The exact estimate is $$\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It can't be solved for real valued p.

By differentiating, you can get that the maximum value occurs where p = 1/20.

This maximum value is less than 0.02 < 1/20.